# Operations on input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this is a stupid question but
What is the correct way of adding subtracting and multiplying values from input boxes in javascript.

Initially I thought for something like y=a+b-e this:

```
$("input").blur(
  function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('input[name="y"]').val(function() {
      sum = $('input[name="a"]').val() + $('input[name="b"]').val() - $('input[name="e"]').val();
      return sum.toFixed(2);
    });

  }
);
```

But I believe this isn't correct. I have created this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOzPre to demonstrate what I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: You're right on the money, `y=a+b-e` would be it, but a value from an input is *always*  a string, and you want to work with numbers, not strings, so you have to convert them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the vals, and set your order of ops (if need be), like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").blur(
    function() {
      var sum = 0;
      $('input[name="y"]').val(function() {
        var valA = parseFloat($('input[name="a"]').val()),
            valB = parseFloat($('input[name="b"]').val()),
            valE = parseFloat($('input[name="e"]').val()),
            sum = (valA + valB) - valE;//set your order of ops here
        return sum.toFixed(2);
      });
    }
  );
});
```

See [this update](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJyvdW)